# Azure API Management - subscription key not being enforced

Tags: azure, api, azure-functions, subscription, azure-api-management

I have an Azure Function that I'm managing via Azure APIM. I have created a subsciption key for it, however it's not being enforced. I've tested accessing it without the subscription key and it can still get a response. Any idea on how I can restrict it so that you have to pass the subscription key in order to get a response?

Here is proof of my active subscription key

[image]

And here if proof that I have Subscription Required enabled

[image]

Comment: How did you test it _without_ passing sub key as a http header , via code or Postman like utility?

Comment: both! I tested via Postman and using fetch() in a client-side app

Answer (score 1):

Able to get the message that subscription key is required for getting the response when testing the Function API that has added in the APIM Instance:

[image]

If we miss the subscription key passing in headers, it enforces to pass the subscription key for getting response:

[image]

If a subscription key is provided, then the result will be successful:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Any idea on how I can restrict it so that you have to pass the subscription key in order to get a response?

If the request is not made with the incorrect or missing the subscription key,

`on-error` section should be executed from the `policies` .

***Example code for on-error in XML:***

```xml
<policies>  
<inbound>  </inbound>  
<backend>  </backend>  
<outbound> </outbound>  
<on-error>  
<!-- If there is an any error -->  
</on-error>  
</policies>
```

As per the Microsoft Documentation, [Predefined errors for built-in steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-error-handling-policies#predefined-errors-for-built-in-steps).

> From the pre-defined error conditions that can occur during the evaluation of built-in processing steps.

Check it for either of the below options on  `authorization`.

> - **`SubscriptionKeyNotFound`**: Access denied due to missing subscription key. Make sure to include subscription key when making
>   requests to API.
> - **`SubscriptionKeyInvalid`**: Access denied due to invalid subscription key. Make sure to provide a valid key for an active
>   subscription.

Thanks `@Vitaliy Kurokhtin`,  see [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57628097/18935775) for additional information.

Comment: The issue with this is that the Echo API (the demo API that comes with setting up APIM) has nothing extra in it's policies XML and yet I receive the correct 401 Error response from that when requesting without a subscription key